# skewness and hypothesis testing (t-test and anova)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution

Some of my variables are heavily positive skewed (left skewed). With log transformation, some are closer to normal distribution, but some are still positively skewed, though not that bad before log transformation.

if I want to compare group means by t-test or Anova, what is the criteria that I know the transformation is good enough, or the transformation is not enough, or need to use non-parametric test?

for example, for the first picture, the log transformation worked well, and I think I can do parametric hypothesis test with the transformed data. 
But for the second picture, the data is still skewed after log transformation. What shall I do in this case? Take another log again, or Go with a non parametric test with original data?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe try with some other types of transformations _e.g._, power transformation? Just an idea. I don't know though how to go about it.

Comment: I was taught to go with your instinct on whether it's good enough. There is definitely an art to statistics. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transformation_%28statistics%29#Common_transformations